# not able to update area info on careers.stackoverflow.com (Error: Email is already registered )

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I dont remember when I tried created a resume on careers.stackoverflow.com long time ago, but today i got a mail from stackoverflow ie:--

```
We’re ..........

Click here to accept the invitation. It’s free!
........

Best wishes,

Joel, Jeff and The Stack Overflow Team
```

After clicking the link i am able to edit all the portions of the resume but not able to edit name, location section cause its giving me an error.

```
 Email is already registered
```

[image]

I tried logout and loginin back and edit my same profile but same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that.  You should be good to go now.