# Careers 2.0 email check bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I received an invite to Careers 2.0; I accepted the invite, and signed in using Google.

The next page prompts me for full name, email and location. I fill the name and the location (leaving  the email as-is), and I get the following error:

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.

It makes no sense to me, since I'm logged in with that email. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Same thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that - both @juancn and @kubal5003 have been fixed

Comment: that's quite lame.. Caused I reported the same issue few months back, at that time team said its resolved... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83729/not-able-to-update-area-info-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-error-email-is-alrea

Comment: @MohitJain Your issue was resolved, the underlying cause is not (which was a known issue at the time of your report). It affects few people so for now posting a meta question or emailing careers (preferred) will take care of it

Comment: I have the same problem now.  Can you help Korneel? (I am now using this system as a communication channel, adding zero value to this article.)

Comment: @ScottFletcher you should be all set

Comment: I've the same problem too

Comment: @gerferra You should be all set now.